# file-upload seems to work, but file isn't in destination folder

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, asyncfileupload

So I am working on a project and I am stuck trying to upload a file. I have gone through multiple tutorials and copied the code into netbeans to see if it would find any errors.  Everything seems okay, but the file isn't in the destination folder after uploading it and I can't figure out why.

I am ajax POSTing the file. Here is my html and jQuery code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <Script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function submit(){

            var $request;
            var $data = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("upload")); 

            // abort pending request
            if ($request) {
                $request.abort();
            }

            var $form = $("#form");
            var $file = $("#file");

                // request to /main.php
                var $request = $.ajax({
                    url: "main.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: $data,
                    processData: false, //tell jQuery not to process the data
                    contentType: false //tell jQuery not to set the contentType
                });

                // on success
                $request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    $("#responseField").html(response).show();
                });

                //on failure
                $request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    console.error(
                        "The following error occured: "+
                        textStatus, errorThrown
                    );
                });

    };
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Prototype Upload Page</h1><br/>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="upload">
        Select .csv file: <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    </form>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="submit()"/>
    <br><textarea id="responseField" rows="4" cols="75"> file upload response: </textarea><br/>
</body>
```

The post gets posted to my main.php on my server. This is the code for that.

```
<?php

if (!empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
    uploadFile();
}

Function uploadFile() {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
      else {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "\n";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "\n";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) .  "kB\n";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "\n";

        if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
          echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"C:/inetpub/wwwroot/test1/afterbreak/uploads/test.csv");
          echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" .$_FILES["file"]["name"];
          }
        }
}
?>
```

I can't figure out what the heck the problem is. I spent a ton of time going through tutorials, trying to get this to work. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Has the user account got write permission to the folder? The user that the application is running as, not the logged in user.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse: You're right. OP, please check if you have the write permission on the folder you are trying to move your file to.

Comment: Plus check if the folder exists. Is `test.csv` by any chance the file you're uploading? Cuz theoretically, any `tmp_name` file uploaded is going to be named `test.csv`.

Comment: How can I discern whether a permissions issue is the problem? The folder does exist, in the same directory as the main.php file. and the folder is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You have a hard coded destination in you move uploaded file `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"C:/inetpub/wwwroot/test1/afterbreak/uploads/test.csv");`. I think you want `"uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]`.

Comment: I had that as the destination initially, but it wasn't working so I tried to hard code the destination to see if that might work instead. I think some of the commenters are correct about it being a permissions issue. Thats the only think I can think of.